# Does $\lim_{y \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} F(x,y) = 0$ force $\lim_{y \to 0}F(x,y) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose 
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} F(x,y) = 0,$$
where $F:\mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable non-negative function.

Can we conclude 
$$\lim_{y \to 0}F(x,y) = 0$$
If not, what else can be said about $F(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think probably about all you can say is that the slice functions $F_y = F(-, y)$ go to 0 in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ as $y \to 0$.  Which doesn't imply anything about pointwise limits $\lim_{y\to 0} F(x,y)$.  (Except for some of the standard consequences of convergence in $L^1$, such as that there is a sequence of $y_n$ with limit 0 such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} F(x, y_n) = 0$ for almost every $x$.)

For instance, consider some examples such as: $F(x, y) = x^{-1} \chi_{[-x^2, x^2]}(y)$.  Or, $F(x, y) = f_{\lfloor 1/y \rfloor}(x)$ where $f_1 = \chi_{[0,1]}, f_2 = \chi_{[0,1/2]}, f_3 = \chi_{[1/2,1]}, f_4 = \chi_{[0,1/4]}, \ldots, f_7 = \chi_{[3/4,1]}, \ldots$ is the "typewriter sequence".

An example somewhat similar in flavor to the typewriter sequence example, but closer to being continuous, would be: $f(x,y) = 1$ if $\sin(1/x) \le y \le x + \sin(1/x)$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise.